# WordPress как в дочерней теме (на отдельных страницах) подключить header и footer родительской темы?

Tags: wordpress, themes

У меня есть родительская тема и дочерняя. На отдельных страницах сайта нужно использовать стили и верстку родительской темы.

На нужных страницах в области контента просто заинклудил файл родительской темы - это заработало. Но хедер и футер виводит дочерню инфу, а нужно родительскую.

Инклуды хедера и футера из родительской не помогли.

Как это можно сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

> Как это можно сделать правильно?

Правильно - ничего не инклудить из родительской темы, а либо создать свой [шаблон страницы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) или [шаблон темы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) и/или использовать функции `get_template_part`, `get_header` и тп.